# Woocommerce: Sorry, this product cannot be purchased

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I made a custom template to work with woocommerce (I have overwritten the existing templates by copying the folder to my theme and renaming it). I added a button on this page that should add the products to the cart using the following link:

```
<a class="add-to-cart" href="?add-to-cart=<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php _e('Add to cart'); ?></a>
```

However, when I go to my cart, I get the following message:

```
Sorry, this product cannot be purchased.
```

The products are of the type 'simple product' and they are added programmatically from an excel file. They are created in the following way:

```
public function handleAutomateRequest() 
{
    $time = time();

    for($_SESSION['records_processed']; $_SESSION['records_processed'] < $_SESSION['record_count']; $_SESSION['records_processed']++)
    {
        $row = $this->create_row_object($_SESSION['records'][$_SESSION['records_processed']]);
        $post = $this->get_post($row);

        $product = array();
        $product['ID'] = !is_null($post) ? $post->id : '';
        $product['post_name'] = $row->slug;
        $product['post_title'] = $row->title;
        $product['post_content'] = '';
        $product['post_type'] = 'product';
        $product['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $product['post_date'] = $row->date;
        $product['post_date_gmt'] = $row->date_gmt;

        if($row->title != '') {
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($product);
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array($row->brand), 'product_cat');

            $this->add_product_meta($post_id, $row);

            update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', '#' . $post_id);
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price', $row->price);
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', $row->price);
        }

        if(time() > $time + 10) 
            break;
    }

    echo $_SESSION['records_processed'] != $_SESSION['record_count'] ? $_SESSION['records_processed'] . ' / ' . $_SESSION['record_count'] : 'DONE';
    die();
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what may be causing the error. After looking around the internet, I have become none the wiser. Any idea on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking into the files...that error message is generated if the product is not purchasable.

One of the tests in the function seems to be

```
 elseif ( $this->get_price() === '' ) {
        $purchasable = false;
```

Which may look for the post_meta _price. So try setting `_price` for each record.

Comment: That did the trick! Weird that setting _regular_price and _sale_price are not enough! :) Thank you!